# Strange behavior for ui-widget in google chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a website that has facebook-like chat built by ui-widget of jQuery.
it works OK on all browsers except google chrome.

When I scroll up or down in Google chrome then my chat would be like this photo:

http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/297334_249816951734849_100001196384982_663733_917094791_n.jpg

What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?